# Restoring Azure VM from Azure recovery Services

Tags: azure, azure-storage, recovery

We have an Azure VM running Windows Server 2012 that is our Azure Virtual Network Domain which became stuck (we can't RDP into it and it is using high CPUs).

The server has been backed up using Azure Recovery Services, but I can't seem to find good documentation for restoring an Azure VM from it. What is the best/right process for recovering a stuck VM (without snapshots) with backups from Recovery Services?

Answer (score 2):

I've identified some documentation on the Azure site (updated July 2015, so it's newer than your post from Aug 2014).

Not sure if you still need this information a year after you submitted your question, but hopefully it will be somewhat useful to you or anyone else who stumbles upon this unanswered question in 2015.

- VM Backup: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms/
- VM Restore: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-restore-vms/

This documentation mentions Azure Recovery Services and Backup/Restore steps for VMs, along with troubleshooting various scenarios.

There's also a VM FAQ at the following URL:

- VM FAQ: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-questions/